# How often should you backup appengine HRD data

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an appengine app, that has about 300GB of data in HRD.. We performed a full backup to google-cloud-storage every night. However this has become costly, costing us 100 dollar per day.

I moved this backup now to once per week. But since the data is in HRD (High Replication DataStore)... Is there really a need for backing up the data?

We cannot afford losing data of more than a day. Thats why we did the daily backup. But this costs us 100 dollar per day.

Regarding HRD, iare backups really needed? What do you recommend.

I know its a business question too, but it also has technical aspects.

Comment: Are you protecting against someone deleting data (be it in code or through the console) or are you against data loss ( ie hardware failure or data-center exploding)?

Comment: Some good reads are the TOS: https://developers.google.com/cloud/terms/data-processing-terms and  WhitePaper: https://cloud.google.com/files/Google-CommonSecurity-WhitePaper-v1.4.pdf

Comment: You could do an incremental backup, i.e. backing up only data that were changed. Have a timestamp field on every (important) entity and then have a cron job querying for this data and export it so GCS or somewhere else.

Comment: Bear in mind if you're backing up to GCS you're simply copying from one part of Google's infrastructure to another, so it doesn't do anything to protect against data loss. Although as Bruyere states if your concern is against deleted data, that's another question.

Comment: @Bruyere i'm protecting against dataloss.

Comment: @PeterKnego Incremental backups are an option. But we are using the backups feature provided by appengine, and it doesnt provide incremental backup: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

Comment: @DanielRoseman thats true. But at least it protects against issues with HRD.

Answer (score 2):

Data stored in HRD is replicated in various regions, so there is no need to perform backups, unless you're afraid data can be modified / deleted via your App or Developers Console.

Comment: Exactly this is my thought too. But I was not 100% sure about it. It seems like doing daily backups for HRD data seems a bit unnecessary. Anyone has more thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Backups to cloud storage do get costly, but you can always download data via shell scripts using  remote_api and bulk loader, then store them on Dropbox, Google Drive or your enterprise NFS:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.

Assuming you are using Python (check Java or Go counterparts if you aren't), you would:

1. Activate the remote_api
2. Create the bulkloader.yaml config using `appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config`
3. Write a script to download the data and setup a cron on one of your local or data center machines.  You would use `appcfg.py download_data` command for this.
4. You can always restore data using `appcfg.py upload_data`

Here's a demo:  http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com

Comment: How would this not get costly? I need a machine that runs and performs this action, and it will still cost datastore read operations. And it will perform badly. The appengine default backup mechanism uses mapreduce on appengine, and scales well. Your solution will take probably too much time. It doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Don't think you can avoid cost in general.  You are either paying for Google App Engine backup and storage costs, or deferring those costs to your own infrastructure.  

The benefits of App Engine are less work for you and ease of use.  The benefits of the other approach would be to have custom and differential/delta backups with an ability to only pull recent and dirty records.  For example, if you have a last_modified stamp, you could create an endpoint where you pass the data model and the last backed up timestamp for that model to get deltas.

Comment: If you don't want the headache of your own data center setup, you can also ship those deltas to BigQuery or Cloud Storage using Pipelines (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery).  Deltas would definitely cost less than entire backups.

Comment: One more point (apologies for the disparate comments):  I have business-critical HRD applications running for 2+ years that have NEVER been backed up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement an incremental backup solution which would download only the updated data since it's unlikely that all 300GB of your data changes daily.

You would need a property like

```
    updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, indexed=True)
```

on every single entity. You don't even have to apply the new index/property to all your existing data (since 1) you already likely to have backups and 2) that would be very expensive)

You then query and backup all entities that were changed since the last backup.

Comment: This would be a theoretical solution. But it requires writing our own backup solution. Currently we use https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin by google. This only provides doing full backups.

Answer (score 0):

Durable Reduced Availability may be appropriate for backups.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/durable-reduced-availability